# MySQL query to group timestamps by days

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp

I have a table of employee sign-ins and I'm trying to generate a summary for the employee of the number of hours he has worked each day this week.

My table looks something like this:

```
id | user | time_in             | time_out            | break
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 6    | 2014-12-14 05:00:00 | 2014-12-14 07:00:00 | 15
2  | 6    | 2014-12-14 09:00:00 | 2014-12-14 14:00:00 | 30
3  | 6    | 2014-12-14 14:00:00 | 2014-12-14 20:00:00 | 0
4  | 6    | 2014-12-15 08:00:00 | 2014-12-15 11:00:00 | 15
```

The `break` value is in minutes, so I'm calculating the employee's hours for the day via `time_out - time_in - 60 * break`. The `time_in` and `time_out` values are of type `TIMESTAMP`.

This is my query so far. It seems to return `null` for `day` and I can't figure out why.

```
SELECT
    SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_out`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_in`) - (`break` * 60)) AS `time`,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time_in`), "%Y-%m-%d") AS `day`
FROM `sign_ins`
WHERE
    `time_in` >= "2014-11-30 00:00:00" AND
    `time_out` <= "2014-12-07 00:00:00" AND
    `user` = 6
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` ASC;
```

Comment: why you are doing `from_unixtime()` for the date values which are already in datetime format `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_in), "%Y-%m-%d") AS day` ?

Comment: I should've mentioned that they are actually of type `TIMESTAMP`. From my understanding, this is the only way to convert them and strip off the time value so that I can use `GROUP` to group them together by day of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the schema above, it doesn't look like you have used timestamp for time_in and time_out fields. So the correction in your query should be..

```
SELECT
    SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_out`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_in`) - (`break` * 60)) AS `time`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`time_in`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `day`
FROM 
    `sign_ins`
WHERE
    `time_in` >= "2014-11-30 00:00:00" AND
    `time_out` <= "2014-12-07 00:00:00" AND
    `user` = 6
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` ASC;
```

Also, I am not sure if you are using it right by subtracting to timestamp to get a time difference. It should be something like..

```
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `time_out`, `time_in`) - (`break` * 60))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have used `TIMESTAMP` as the type, but removing the `FROM_UNIXTIME` worked for me. Also thanks for the suggestion for `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, I'll look into it.